# Parse.com Order By with arithmetic calc

Tags: android, parse-platform

Can I query DB and sort by some simple arithmetic calculation in parse.com API?

for example I have the following DB in SQL:

```
User    Value1  Value2
John      1       5
Siri      2       3
Sam       3       2
```

I would like to perform the following query:

```
select user from DB order by (value1*2 +value2*3)
```

It's easy in SQL.  If each row is a parse object, how can I accomplish it with parse.com API?

I know there is `query.orderByAscending("value1");` but I would like it to be with the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately sorting by calculated fields on Parse is not supported.

See https://www.parse.com/questions/sorting-by-calculated-fields

Comment: tnx. i thought that will be the answer. if i have "weights" that can be configured by user it is "bad" solution. For now i will go with it.